# docker elasticsearch container not forwarding port (macOs)

Tags: elasticsearch, docker

I have a container set up to run elasticsearch. The service starts but I can't connect to it via curl or the browser.

```
 RUN \
 cd /tmp && \
 wget https://download.elasticsearch.org/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-  1.3.2.tar.gz && \
 tar xvzf elasticsearch-1.3.2.tar.gz && \
 rm -f elasticsearch-1.3.2.tar.gz && \
 mv /tmp/elasticsearch-1.3.2 /elasticsearch

 # Define mountable directories.
 VOLUME ["/data"]

 # Define default command.
  CMD ["/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch"]

 EXPOSE 9200
 EXPOSE 9300
```

Connecting to `http://localhost:9200` yields nothing. The docker ps shows ports;

```
 0.0.0.0:49179->9200/tcp, 0.0.0.0:49180->9300/tcp
 ...
 net::ERR_ADDRESS_UNREACHABLE
```

Am I missing some config value? THANKS!

[Update] I also tried the -p in the run command

```
 docker run -i -p 9200:9200 -p 9300:9300 -t --rm -P team1/image1
```

Comment: Elasticsearch by default only listens on localhost. My guess is that Docker port mappings would require ES to listen on the non-localhost interface in the docker image.

Comment: I had the same problem and it's answered below by @Guam Wang. If you wouldn't mind, can you specify the OS that you were running this in as part of the question? It was the root of my problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I tested your Dockerfile, but it just works.

```
FROM dockerfile/java
RUN \
  cd /tmp && \
  wget https://download.elasticsearch.org/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-1.3.2.tar.gz && \
  tar xvzf elasticsearch-1.3.2.tar.gz && \
  rm -f elasticsearch-1.3.2.tar.gz && \
  mv /tmp/elasticsearch-1.3.2 /elasticsearch
# Define mountable directories.                                                                                    
VOLUME ["/data"]
# Define default command.                                                                                          
CMD ["/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch"]
EXPOSE 9200
EXPOSE 9300
```

I try to build this Dockerfile and run it.

```
$ docker build -t 25312935 .
$ docker run -t -p 9200:9200 -p 9300:9300 --rm 25312935
[2014-08-15 04:41:08,349][INFO ][node                     ] [Black Crow] version[1.3.2], pid[1], build[dee175d/2014-08-13T14:29:30Z]
[2014-08-15 04:41:08,349][INFO ][node                     ] [Black Crow] initializing ...
[2014-08-15 04:41:08,353][INFO ][plugins                  ] [Black Crow] loaded [], sites []
[2014-08-15 04:41:10,444][INFO ][node                     ] [Black Crow] initialized
[2014-08-15 04:41:10,444][INFO ][node                     ] [Black Crow] starting ...
[2014-08-15 04:41:10,547][INFO ][transport                ] [Black Crow] bound_address {inet[/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9300]}, publish_address {inet[/172.17.0.72:9300]}
[2014-08-15 04:41:10,560][INFO ][discovery                ] [Black Crow] elasticsearch/0mpczYoYSZCiAmbkxcsfpg
[2014-08-15 04:41:13,601][INFO ][cluster.service          ] [Black Crow] new_master [Black Crow][0mpczYoYSZCiAmbkxcsfpg][eeb3396b1ecc][inet[/172.17.0.72:9300]], reason: zen-disco-join (elected_as_master)
[2014-08-15 04:41:13,615][INFO ][http                     ] [Black Crow] bound_address {inet[/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9200]}, publish_address {inet[/172.17.0.72:9200]}
[2014-08-15 04:41:13,615][INFO ][node                     ] [Black Crow] started
[2014-08-15 04:41:13,634][INFO ][gateway                  ] [Black Crow] recovered [0] indices into cluster_state
```

As you can see below, request `127.0.0.1:9200` returns json response.

```
$ curl 127.0.0.1:9200
{
  "status" : 200,
  "name" : "Black Crow",
  "version" : {
"number" : "1.3.2",
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

Check your `-p` option. It means publising container's port to host. If you doesn't write explicitly host's port, docker assign random port like below.

```
$ docker run -t -p 9200 -p 9300 --rm 25312935
$ docker ps -l
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                COMMAND                CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                              NAMES
1aa4c2c84d04        25312935:latest      /elasticsearch/bin/e   15 seconds ago      Up 15 seconds       0.0.0.0:49153->9200/tcp, 0.0.0.0:49154->9300/tcp   sad_shockley
```

`0.0.0.0:49153->9200/tcp` means that you can access container's 9200 port through host's 49153 port.

```
$ curl 127.0.0.1:49153
{
  "status" : 200,
  "name" : "Golem",
  "version" : {
"number" : "1.3.2",
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

So if you want to use host`s 9200 port, explicitly write the host port like`-p 9200:9200`or`-p 0.0.0.0:9200:9200`

```
$ docker ps -l
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                COMMAND                CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                            NAMES
eeb3396b1ecc        25312935:latest      /elasticsearch/bin/e   59 seconds ago      Up 58 seconds       0.0.0.0:9200->9200/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9300->9300/tcp   high_elion
```

If this still doesn't work, try to `--net=host` option. You can use the host network stack inside the container by using this option.

```
$ docker run -t --net=host --rm 25312935
$ curl 127.0.0.1:9200
{
  "status" : 200,
  "name" : "Black Crow",
  "version" : {
"number" : "1.3.2",
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

If both don't work, I think that you need to check your other network configuration.

Comment: Ugh! "curl: (7) Failed connect to 0.0.0.0:49200; Connection refused" Thank you @nacyot ! Looks like you're correct, it's some other network config issue the --net=host didn't work either.

Comment: BTW, what OS are you using? I've tried on 2 OS X and failed but it works on an ubuntu box

Comment: Looks like docker bug in OSX...I don't see the ports open netstat -an | grep 'LISTEN'

Answer (score 15):

If you are running docker on OSX, note that the host is really the VirtualBox instance that was installed when you initialized boot2docker.  So in this situation, instead of using:

`curl http://localhost:9200`

find the IP of the virtual box instance using, which I'll denote as VM_IP:

`boot2docker ip`

then try:

`curl http://<VM_IP>:9200`

Comment: Bang on, I would never have thought to even specify the original OS as part of the question. This solved my problem too.

Comment: You can also do directly: curl $(boot2docker ip):9200

Comment: This is not true anymore if you use "Docker for Mac"

Answer (score 11):

I had an issue with port forwarding when running Elasticsearch in a docker container. I solved the problem by manually specifying which interfaces to  bind Elasticsearch server `docker run --rm -p 9200:9200 -p 9300:9300 --name=es elasticsearch:latest -Des.network.host=0.0.0.0`.

The binding part is the `-Des.network.host=0.0.0.0` at the end. I wrote a blog post detailing this at https://mad.is/2016/09/running-elasticsearch-in-docker-container/

Comment: Binding `0.0.0.0` works for me.

You can specify this in docker-compse.yml as an environment variable like this;
`SERVER_HOST: "0.0.0.0"`

Answer (score 2):

Someone using **Docker for Mac** can use `docker.for.mac.localhost` as a host for Elasticsearch.

```
curl http://docker.for.mac.localhost:9200
```

I had similar issue and changing the host worked for me