# Unable to access elasticsearch running in docker on mac OS X

Tags: docker, elasticsearch

I went through this SO [ques](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25312935/docker-elasticsearch-container-not-forwarding-port-macos) but still couldn't make it work. I followed [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docker.html) elasticsearch tutorial to run it in dev mode with:

`docker run -p 9200:9200 -p 9300:9300 -e "discovery.type=single-node" docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.2.4`

Elasticsearch starts but still I am unable to reach it with curl or browser. These are the logs:

```
docker run -p 9200:9200 -p 9300:9300 -e "discovery.type=single-node" 
docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.2.4

[2018-06-08T08:35:59,131][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [] initializing ...
[2018-06-08T08:35:59,209][INFO ][o.e.e.NodeEnvironment    ] [vMpk2HC] using [1] data paths, mounts [[/ (overlay)]], net usable_space [31.7gb], net total_space [37.2gb], types [overlay]
[2018-06-08T08:35:59,209][INFO ][o.e.e.NodeEnvironment    ] [vMpk2HC] heap size [1007.3mb], compressed ordinary object pointers [true]
[2018-06-08T08:35:59,211][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] node name [vMpk2HC] derived from node ID [vMpk2HCTQNKxTMFmkE-0oA]; set [node.name] to override
[2018-06-08T08:35:59,211][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] version[6.2.4], pid[1], build[ccec39f/2018-04-12T20:37:28.497551Z], OS[Linux/4.9.0-0.bpo.2-amd64/amd64], JVM[Oracle Corporation/OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM/1.8.0_161/25.161-b14]
[2018-06-08T08:35:59,212][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] JVM arguments [-Xms1g, -Xmx1g, -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC, -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75, -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly, -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch, -Xss1m, -Djava.awt.headless=true, -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8, -Djna.nosys=true, -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow, -Dio.netty.noUnsafe=true, -Dio.netty.noKeySetOptimization=true, -Dio.netty.recycler.maxCapacityPerThread=0, -Dlog4j.shutdownHookEnabled=false, -Dlog4j2.disable.jmx=true, -Djava.io.tmpdir=/tmp/elasticsearch.muZEBoID, -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError, -XX:+PrintGCDetails, -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps, -XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution, -XX:+PrintGCApplicationStoppedTime, -Xloggc:logs/gc.log, -XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation, -XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=32, -XX:GCLogFileSize=64m, -Des.cgroups.hierarchy.override=/, -Des.path.home=/usr/share/elasticsearch, -Des.path.conf=/usr/share/elasticsearch/config]
[2018-06-08T08:36:01,407][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [vMpk2HC] loaded module [aggs-matrix-stats]
[2018-06-08T08:36:01,407][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [vMpk2HC] loaded module [analysis-common]
[2018-06-08T08:36:01,407][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [vMpk2HC] loaded module [ingest-common]
[2018-06-08T08:36:01,407][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [vMpk2HC] loaded module [lang-expression]
[2018-06-08T08:36:01,407][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [vMpk2HC] loaded module [lang-mustache]
[2018-06-08T08:36:01,407][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [vMpk2HC] loaded module [lang-painless]
[2018-06-08T08:36:01,408][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [vMpk2HC] loaded module [mapper-extras]
[2018-06-08T08:36:01,408][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [vMpk2HC] loaded module [parent-join]
[2018-06-08T08:36:01,408][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [vMpk2HC] loaded module [percolator]
[2018-06-08T08:36:01,408][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [vMpk2HC] loaded module [rank-eval]
[2018-06-08T08:36:01,408][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [vMpk2HC] loaded module [reindex]
[2018-06-08T08:36:01,408][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [vMpk2HC] loaded module [repository-url]
[2018-06-08T08:36:01,408][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [vMpk2HC] loaded module [transport-netty4]
[2018-06-08T08:36:01,408][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [vMpk2HC] loaded module [tribe]
[2018-06-08T08:36:01,409][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [vMpk2HC] loaded plugin [ingest-geoip]
[2018-06-08T08:36:01,409][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [vMpk2HC] loaded plugin [ingest-user-agent]
[2018-06-08T08:36:01,409][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [vMpk2HC] loaded plugin [x-pack-core]
[2018-06-08T08:36:01,409][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [vMpk2HC] loaded plugin [x-pack-deprecation]
[2018-06-08T08:36:01,409][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [vMpk2HC] loaded plugin [x-pack-graph]
[2018-06-08T08:36:01,410][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [vMpk2HC] loaded plugin [x-pack-logstash]
[2018-06-08T08:36:01,410][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [vMpk2HC] loaded plugin [x-pack-ml]
[2018-06-08T08:36:01,410][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [vMpk2HC] loaded plugin [x-pack-monitoring]
[2018-06-08T08:36:01,410][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [vMpk2HC] loaded plugin [x-pack-security]
[2018-06-08T08:36:01,410][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [vMpk2HC] loaded plugin [x-pack-upgrade]
[2018-06-08T08:36:01,410][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [vMpk2HC] loaded plugin [x-pack-watcher]
[2018-06-08T08:36:05,966][INFO ][o.e.x.m.j.p.l.CppLogMessageHandler] [controller/104] [Main.cc@128] controller (64 bit): Version 6.2.4 (Build 524e7fe231abc1) Copyright (c) 2018 Elasticsearch BV
[2018-06-08T08:36:06,529][INFO ][o.e.d.DiscoveryModule    ] [vMpk2HC] using discovery type [single-node]
[2018-06-08T08:36:07,313][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] initialized
[2018-06-08T08:36:07,313][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [vMpk2HC] starting ...
[2018-06-08T08:36:07,457][INFO ][o.e.t.TransportService   ] [vMpk2HC] publish_address {172.17.0.2:9300}, bound_addresses {0.0.0.0:9300}
[2018-06-08T08:36:07,488][WARN ][o.e.b.BootstrapChecks    ] [vMpk2HC] max virtual memory areas vm.max_map_count [65530] is too low, increase to at least [262144]
[2018-06-08T08:36:07,520][INFO ][o.e.x.s.t.n.SecurityNetty4HttpServerTransport] [vMpk2HC] publish_address {172.17.0.2:9200}, bound_addresses {0.0.0.0:9200}
[2018-06-08T08:36:07,520][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [vMpk2HC] started
[2018-06-08T08:36:07,698][INFO ][o.e.g.GatewayService     ] [vMpk2HC] recovered [0] indices into cluster_state
[2018-06-08T08:36:08,241][INFO ][o.e.l.LicenseService     ] [vMpk2HC] license [70cc45f9-4b48-4c75-a3db-9e469d607f3e] mode [basic] - valid
[2018-06-08T08:36:17,455][INFO ][o.e.c.m.MetaDataCreateIndexService] [vMpk2HC] [.monitoring-es-6-2018.06.08] creating index, cause [auto(bulk api)], templates [.monitoring-es], shards [1]/[0], mappings [doc]
[2018-06-08T08:36:17,751][INFO ][o.e.c.r.a.AllocationService] [vMpk2HC] Cluster health status changed from [YELLOW] to [GREEN] (reason: [shards started [[.monitoring-es-6-2018.06.08][0]] ...]).
```

I installed docker with homebrew using `brew install docker docker-compose docker-machine xhyve docker-machine-driver-xhyve` and elasticsearch with `brew install elasticsearch`

If I try to install elasticsearch with homebrew and start it on my local machine, it works. But docker container doesn't.

Comment: Can you share how are you trying to request ES via curl/browser?

Comment: Just a basic `curl http://localhost:9200`

Comment: should be working, is your container still running when you test? I remember in the past I needed enough memory to run those images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure what was the problem. But I uninstalled my docker and installed it again with the dmg file provided by docker. 
It works now and I am finally able to access elasticsearch :)

Answer (score 0):

Looks good to me, no errors in the logs. You need to connect using the IP address you can see in the logs and all will be fine

```
curl http://172.17.0.2:9200
```

If you log into the container, you can access your ES with `curl http://localhost:9200`, but since you're on the host, you need to use the IP address that the container published ES to.

Comment: What response do you get?

Comment: "Could not get response from localhost:9200"

Comment: yes, that's why you need to use `172.17.0.2:9200` and not `localhost:9200`